# yii Looping series name of array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, yii, indexing

I have array as below:

```
radiolist = array (k1=>'1',k2=>'3',k3=>'2',k4=>'1',k5=>'2',k6=>'2');
```

in my form i want to repeat those array index and value based on this code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($radiolist)-1; $i++) {  
  echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'k[$i]',array('1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3'));
  //'k[$i]' repeated to be k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6   
}
```

i want this output:

```
<input type="radio" name="school[k1]" value="1" /> 1
<input type="radio" name="school[k1]" value="2" /> 2
<input type="radio" name="school[k1]" value="3" /> 3
.
.
.
<input type="radio" name="school[k6]" value="1" /> 1
<input type="radio" name="school[k6]" value="2" /> 2
<input type="radio" name="school[k6]" value="3" /> 3
```

im really confused how to do it. please any advise are highly appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to repeat those array index and value, radioButtonList() it self will do it for you.

```
<?php $radiolist = array ('k1'=>'1','k2'=>'3','k3'=>'2','k4'=>'1','k5'=>'2','k6'=>'2');  ?>
<?php echo $form->radioButtonList($model,'school',$radiolist,
   array(
     'template'=>'{input}{label}',
     'separator'=>'',
     'labelOptions'=>array(
            'style'=> '
                padding-left:13px;
                width: 60px;
                float: left;
            '),

      ));?>
?>
```

Comment: still not exactly what i want. it's become a problem when i use to update my form.

Answer (score 0):

after trying several combination, here are my solution:

```
$k = array ('k1','k2','k3','k4','k5','k6');

for ($i = 0; $i <= count($k)-1; $i++) {  
   echo $form->radioButtonList($model,$k[$i], array('1'=>'1','2'=>'2','3'=>'3'));
   //$k[$i] would repeated to be k1, k2, k3, k4, k5, k6   
   //$i as index or use other index as u want.
}
```

many thanks for all advice.
Cheers.